# ARM7 32-bit Branch Offset Calculator

Tags: ida, arm, patching, patch-reversing

I need to patch an arm7 program by replacing this fopen function by another function.

```
.text:00018D68 52 D7 FF EB                       BL              fopen

...

.plt:0000EAB8 ; FILE *fopen(const char *filename, const char *modes)
```

Do you know how to calculate the 24 bits that I need to write after EB?
The documentation is not very clear. I tried to find a Branch offset calculator but not found.

Thx,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use https://www.keystone-engine.org/showcase/ assembler

```
from keystone import *
target = 0xDEADBEEF
current = 0x18D68
ks = Ks(KS_ARCH_ARM, KS_MODE_ARM)
bytes(ks.asm("bl {}".format(hex(target)), current)[0]).hex()
```

Comment: It's working!! Thank you